# How can I reset my TextEditor > C# > Code Style settings to the default or a previous version in VS 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting

They don't seem to be exported in vssettings etc. I don't see a way to restore them to an earlier version or even the default out-of-the-box Visual Studio settings ...

Restoring all settings also does not help.

Comment: I dont know why you mark this as duplicate since a) it has nothing to do with Resharper and b) the problem persists even after doing "Reset all settings" (it still remembers my latest change in t he respective options dialog)

Comment: do you have an editorconfig file?

Comment: In some of my projects, yes. But I want to be able to play around with settings and then go back to a previous/default state regardless of editorconfig files ...

Comment: have you find a way? I have the same issue here, vs2022

Comment: No, sorry.I now just use .editorconfig files in all my projects, and when I create a new solution, copying the .editorconfig that represents my default settings is one of my first orders of business.